# grouping on string fields in R

Tags: r, grouping, data.table, plyr

I have a data frame like this:

```
         date      time userid        status
1  02/25/2012  09:22:10   aabc     logged_in
2  02/25/2012  09:30:10   aabc    logged_out
3  02/25/2012  09:29:20   abbc    logged_out
4  02/25/2012  09:27:30    abc     logged_in
5  02/25/2012  09:26:29    abc  login_failed
6  02/25/2012  09:26:39    abc  login_failed
7  02/25/2012  09:26:52    abc  login_failed
8  02/25/2012  09:27:09    abc  login_failed
9  02/25/2012  09:27:20    abc  login_failed
10 02/25/2012  09:24:10   abdc     logged_in
11 02/25/2012  09:24:12   abdc    logged_out
12 02/25/2012  09:22:10   abhc     logged_in
13 02/25/2012  09:30:10   abuc     logged_in
14 02/25/2012  09:30:14   abuc    logged_out
15 02/25/2012  09:29:40    baa     logged_in
```

I want to the userids, status and "count" of the login_failures for each userid. I did this:

`ddply(mytbl, c('userid', 'status'), function(x) c(count=nrow(x)))` , but this gives the count for all userids. I want to restrict my output to only those userids whose status is 'login _failed'. Any ideas? I have seen questions on grouping by numeric fields, but, none on strings.

I am not very familiar with all the plyr features. It will great to see how this can be done using summarize, aggregate, sqldf, data.table etc. Slowly understanding each of them.

Thanks
Sri

Comment: What would your desired output look like for this sample data? A single row `data.frame`?

Comment: Yes, a single row data.frame: abc      login_failed    5

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
require(data.table)
DT = as.data.table(mytbl)

DT[status=="login_failed", .N, by=userid]
```

To name the column :

```
DT[status=="login_failed", list(failed_logins=.N), by=userid]
```

Comment: Data.table is awesome, crisp and intuitive. Thanks very much. Learning all the tricks of plyr and data.table now :-) Thanks again.

Comment: @user1717931 Thanks, nice to hear. This syntax will scale for large datasets, too. Don't forget to accept one of the answers.

Comment: @MatthewDowle, very nice. I've just started experimenting with your "data.table" package.

Comment: @mrdwab Cool. I'm keen to capture those first frustrations you're bound to have when you start looking, so any suggestions you have are most welcome. The very top of `?data.table` gives tips for the fastest approach.

Comment: I read your fast intro to data.table. I shall keep in mind about binary-search option. It will surely be handy for me as I deal with large data sets.

Comment: @MatthewDowle, is that a vector scan? Does the following do the same thing, and would it be faster/preferable?: `setkey(DT, status); DT[J('login_failed'), .N, by=userid]`

Comment: @GSee Hi. On one column a vector scan is probably faster than `setkey`+join. Since a `setkey` has to scan the whole column anyway as part of the sorting process. Setting the key would be preferable when run once before several joins to it, or in compound vector scans like `col1==val1 & col2==val2`. The example in the intro vignette is like that. I just retested to make sure and the time to key is 1.6s + 0.01 for the join, compared to 6.9s for `DF[DF$x=="R" & DF$y=="h",]`. So there it is worth setting the key, even for a single join. Only in a single `col1==val1` might vector scan be ok.

Answer (score 2):

```
ddply(mytbl, .(userid), transform, 
failed_logins = length(which(status=="login_failed")))
```

Following up on Brian Diggs' point, I wrote the above because I assumed you wanted this information appended to the original dataset. If not, and you just need a summary, replace `transform` with `summarise`.

Comment: I think you want `summarise`, not `transform`.

Comment: Good point, I wasn't sure if the OP wanted this appended to the data or if he wanted a summary. I was assuming the former.

Answer (score 2):

Slightly different approach than @Maiasaura. I filter to just the failed logins and then summarize. The difference would be whether those `userid`'s with logins, but no failed logins, appear in the final result with 0's or not.

```
ddply(mytbl[mytbl$status=="login_failed",], .(userid), 
  summarise, failed_logins=length(status))
```

This gives

```
> ddply(mytbl[mytbl$status=="login_failed",], .(userid), 
+   summarise, failed_logins=length(status))
  userid failed_logins
1    abc             5
```

To complete the approaches, if you want all the `userid`'s:

```
ddply(mytbl, .(userid), 
  summarise, failed_logins = sum(status=="login_failed"))
```

which gives

```
> ddply(mytbl, .(userid), 
+   summarise, failed_logins = sum(status=="login_failed"))
  userid failed_logins
1   aabc             0
2   abbc             0
3    abc             5
4   abdc             0
5   abhc             0
6   abuc             0
7    baa             0
```

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions. I am trying to replicate these in RStudio...and something is wrong.> `ddply(mytbl[mytbl$status=="login_failed",], .(userid), summarise, failed_logins=length(status))
[1] date   time   userid status
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
>`

Comment: never mind my previous error. I had a leading space for the string "login_failed". In the table, it was " login_failed". Hence, the problem with output and my experiments with subset. Thanks to all.

Comment: Somehow I just saw this answer. Seems like pretty much the same conceptual approach I used for `aggregate()`. +1, of course!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a base R solution using `aggregate()`:

```
setNames(aggregate(status ~ userid,
                   mytbl[mytbl$status == "login_failed", ],
                   function(x) length(x)),
         c("userid", "failed_logins"))
#   userid failed_logins
# 1    abc             5
```

#### Update

Another useful function that comes to mind is `ave()` which you can use in the following way:

- First, use `ave()` to add a new column into your dataset that takes the running count for each activity by each user. (**Note**: I had to make sure the "userid" and "status" columns were *character* class, not *factors* to get this to work for me).

  ```
  mytbl$status_seq <- ave(mytbl$status, mytbl$userid, 
                          mytbl$status, FUN = seq_along)
  head(mytbl)
  #         date     time userid       status status_seq
  # 1 02/25/2012 09:22:10   aabc    logged_in          1
  # 2 02/25/2012 09:30:10   aabc   logged_out          1
  # 3 02/25/2012 09:29:20   abbc   logged_out          1
  # 4 02/25/2012 09:27:30    abc    logged_in          1
  # 5 02/25/2012 09:26:29    abc login_failed          1
  # 6 02/25/2012 09:26:39    abc login_failed          2
  ```
- Second, use `aggregate()` as demonstrated earlier, subsetting for the condition that you're interested in, and retrieving the `max` value.

  ```
  aggregate(status_seq ~ userid, 
            mytbl[mytbl$status == "login_failed", ],
            function(x) max(x))
  #   userid status_seq
  # 1    abc          5

  aggregate(status_seq ~ userid, 
            mytbl[mytbl$status == "logged_out", ],
            function(x) max(x))
  #   userid status_seq
  # 1   aabc          1
  # 2   abbc          1
  # 3   abdc          1
  # 4   abuc          1
  ```

Note that `ave()` might be even more interesting if you used

```
mytbl$status_seq <- ave(mytbl$status, mytbl$date, mytbl$userid, mytbl$status, 
                        FUN = seq_along)
```

since that will reset the counter for each new day in your dataset.

Finally (at the risk of sharing a solution that might be *too* obvious), since you're only interested in counts, you might want to explore `table()`, which gives you all the information at once:

```
table(mytbl$userid, mytbl$status)
# 
#      logged_in logged_out login_failed
# aabc         1          1            0
# abbc         0          1            0
# abc          1          0            5
# abdc         1          1            0
# abhc         1          0            0
# abuc         1          1            0
# baa          1          0            0
```

Comment: Thanks. I have experimented with this and "table" is very helpful.

Comment: @user1717931, FYI, if you prefer your `table` as a `data.frame`, use `as.data.frame.matrix(table(mytbl$userid, mytbl$status))`. Also, do be sure to up-vote answers that you find helpful; if one of the answers solves your problem as desired, be sure to "accept" it too.